Can we call $\frac{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)}=\frac{a d}{b c}$ a Law of exponents?

Can we call $\frac{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)}=\frac{a d}{b c}$ a Law of exponents?

Sorry if my question is silly.
I proved this using the well known laws of exponents $\frac{1}{a^{-1}}=a$, $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{-n}=\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n$
Here is my proof:
$$\begin{aligned}
& \frac{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)}=\frac{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)^{1}}=\frac{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{\left(\frac{d}{c}\right)^{-1}} \\
\Rightarrow & \frac{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)}=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) \times \frac{1}{\left(\frac{d}{c}\right)^{-1}} \\
\Rightarrow & \frac{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)}=\frac{a}{b} \times\left(\frac{d}{c}\right)^{1}=\frac{a d}{b c}
\end{aligned}$$
So My question is, can we treat this as Law of exponents, since we used laws of exponents to get this. Also Is my proof simple? or is there a better proof?

Interesting question. I would say it is a consequence of one of the laws of exponents rather than a law in its own right, but that is perhaps semantics.

This identity has no more to do with exponents than $(a-b)-(c-d)=(a+d)-(b+c)$ has to do with multiplication.

@RedFive It's not a consequence of those laws, it's the reason that negative exponents correspond to division. Using to to establish division rules is circular reasoning.

I think it seems circular as law of exponents  are derived from knowing division is the inverse of mulitplication.  Als is $(\frac ab)^{-n} = (\frac ba)^n$ actually one of the laws.  Isn't it that $(\frac ab)^{-n} =\frac 1{(\frac ab)^n}=(\frac 1{\frac ab})^n$ two laws of exponents and $\frac 1{\frac ab}=\frac ba$ a law of recipricals which is essentially what you are trying to prove anyway?  [I've never seen the law $(\frac ab)^{-n}=(\frac ba)^n$ stated that way before, ever.]  Still it's an interesting observation but I doubt there's anything direct to say about it.

"Law of exponents" usually means "A law about exponents," so I certainly wouldn't choose this name for this theorem. You can call things whatever you want, but it is generally wise to stick to names that won't confuse your readers, if your goal is communication.

You probably shouldn't. This law is just about division, which is one very small case of exponentiation.
It's kind of like getting a parking ticket, and describing it as "I broke the law" - technically true, but more likely to bring confusion than clarity.
Additionally, you are most likely making a circular argument* - the thing you've "proved" about division was used in defining negative exponents, (and showing that the definition is consistent with the usual laws of exponentiation).
There are multiple ways to approach defining exponents, but you're going to have to use something like one of the key, provable facts of division (identified by by @fleablood):
$$\frac{1}{\frac{a}{b}} = \frac{b}{a}.$$
I'd say this is more or less equivalent to what you've proved, and it is baked in to the definition of exponentiation with negative numbers. So it's not surprising to see it pop back out.
Oh, and I re-read your question, and realized you asked if there is a better/simpler proof. There's always a question of how explicit you want to be about small details, but for me
$$\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{a}{b}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{d}{c} = \frac{ad}{bc}$$
seems the neatest. But doing all these manipulations are good practice, and help us learn to spot patterns, so I encourage you to keep at it.

* Several commenters have already mentioned this, but comments can disappear, so I'm adding it to this answer.

+1 More is true. Since you need the meaning of division to extend the laws of exponents to negative exponents,   this is not just inadvisable, it's really circular reasoning. I think you should add this to your answer, to short circuit all the wrong comments and answers.

@EthanBolker - Heh, while I was making breakfast I started to wonder if I should add something about probable circular reasoning. Your comment convinced me. Done.

In a sense, there is no such thing as division. There is only multiplication and what we call division is multiplying by the multiplicative inverse. Then, if you are multiplying by some factor, while you are multiplying by the first power of that factor, this is only an exponent in a trivial sense that doesn't actually introduce the concept of exponentiation as a new entity different from multiplication. You need an exponent with absolute value greater than or less than one. Otherwise you just have multiplication/division. Further, you generally don't want to use a more complicated concept when a simpler one applies. In the case of the ratio of two rationals, it suffices to multiply by the reciprocal of the denominator. While compatible with rules of exponentiation, it fails to illustrate them.

Can we treat$?$ Of course we can.
The rule that whenever a fraction is divided, we have to multiply by its reciprocal is a direct consequence of this law.

No, this is backwards. You use the fact that division is multiplication by the reciprocal to define the meaning of negative exponents.
